# backtracking not trying all possibilities

Tags: python, backtracking

so I've got a list of questions as a dictionary, e.g

```
{"Question1": 3, "Question2": 5 ... }
```

That means the "Question1" has 3  points, the second one has 5, etc.

I'm trying to create all subset of question that have between a certain number of questions and points.

I've tried something like

```
questions = {"Q1":1, "Q2":2, "Q3": 1, "Q4" : 3, "Q5" : 1, "Q6" : 2}
u = 3  #
v = 5 # between u and v questions


x = 5   #
y = 10 #between x and y points


solution = []
n = 0

def main(n_):
        global n
        n = n_

        global solution
        solution = []

        finalSolution = []

        for x in questions.keys():
                solution.append("_")

        finalSolution.extend(Backtracking(0))

        return finalSolution


def Backtracking(k):

        finalSolution = []

        for c in questions.keys():
                solution[k] = c
                print ("candidate: ", solution)
                if not reject(k):
                    print ("not rejected: ", solution)
                    if accept(k):
                                finalSolution.append(list(solution))
                    else:
                                finalSolution.extend(Backtracking(k+1))

        return finalSolution


def reject(k):
    if solution[k] in solution: #if the question already exists
        return True
    if k > v: #too many questions
        return True
    points = 0
    for x in solution:
        if x in questions.keys():
            points = points + questions[x]
    if points > y: #too many points
        return True
    return False



def accept(k):

    points = 0
    for x in solution:
        if x in questions.keys():
            points = points + questions[x]
    if points in range (x, y+1) and k in range (u, v+1):
        return True
    return False


print(main(len(questions.keys())))
```

but it's not trying all possibilities, only putting all the questions on the first index..

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your check `solution[k] in solution` in `reject` is always going to be `True`. You're also missing the actual backtracking step, where you undo the changes you've made to the program state (i.e. resetting `solution[k]` to `"_"` before returning from `Backtracking`). That *might* actually be OK for this problem (since the order of the items in the solution doesn't matter), but it makes the name of your function rather misleading.

Comment: Gotcha, I replaced that `solution[k] in solution` with `solution.count(solution[k]) != 1` , I believe that is ok, also added `solution[k] = "_"` before `finalSolution.extend(Backtracking(k+1))` but still it doesn't seem to work

It just does `Q1, _, _, _ , _, _` ,  `_, Q1,_ , _ , _, _` and so on then exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems with your code.

The first issue is that the first check in your `reject` function is always `True`. You can fix that in a variety of ways (you commented that you're now using `solution.count(solution[k]) != 1`).

The second issue is that your `accept` function uses the variable name `x` for what it intends to be two different things (a question from `solution` in the `for` loop and the global `x` that is the minimum number of points). That doesn't work, and you'll get a `TypeError` when trying to pass it to `range`. A simple fix is to rename the loop variable (I suggest `q` since it's a key into `questions`). Checking if a value is `in` a `range` is also a bit awkward. It's usually much nicer to use chained comparisons: `if x <= points <= y and u <= k <= v`

The third issue is that you're not backtracking at all. The backtracking step needs to reset the global `solution` list to the same state it had before `Backtracking` was called. You can do this at the end of the function, just before you `return`, using `solution[k] = "_"` (you commented that you've added this line, but I think you put it in the wrong place).

Anyway, here's a fixed version of your functions:

```
def Backtracking(k):
        finalSolution = []
        for c in questions.keys():
                solution[k] = c
                print ("candidate: ", solution)
                if not reject(k):
                    print ("not rejected: ", solution)
                    if accept(k):
                                finalSolution.append(list(solution))
                    else:
                                finalSolution.extend(Backtracking(k+1))
        solution[k] = "_"    # backtracking step here!
        return finalSolution

def reject(k):
    if solution.count(solution[k]) != 1: # fix this condition
        return True
    if k > v:
        return True
    points = 0
    for q in solution:
        if q in questions:
            points = points + questions[q]
    if points > y: #too many points
        return True
    return False

def accept(k):
    points = 0
    for q in solution:  # change this loop variable (also done above, for symmetry)
        if q in questions:
            points = points + questions[q]
    if x <= points <= y and u <= k <= v:  # chained comparisons are much nicer than range
        return True
    return False
```

There are still things that could probably be improved in there. I think having `solution` be a fixed-size global list with dummy values is especially unpythonic (a dynamically growing list that you pass as an argument would be much more natural). I'd also suggest using `sum` to add up the points rather than using an explicit loop of your own.

Comment: I noticed that I'm using the same variable in the for loop as the global one, fixed that right after I posted my last comment.

But program still didn't work tho, because I used `solution[k] = "_"` in the else of accept instead of before the return.

Now that I fixed that too it seems to be working. Thanks a lot for taking your time helping me and explaining everything. You were really helpful!

Comment: I've noticed a problem tho. It only returns solutions that are length of `u+1` , despite having more possibilities.  Not sure if I can link my code to external sources but I believe it will be easier to read that way so [there you go](https://codeshare.io/5zldBj) if you wanna take a look too.

Comment: Ah, I'd left an [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) in the code in the answer that I'd fixed on my end in a later version. All the comparisons should use `<=` instead of `<`. I've edited the answer to fix that, but you should probably double check that the bounds match what they're supposed to for your problem.

Comment: Yea, I've noticed it and fixed that, still don't know yet why I still get only `u+1` length answers